# Heroku php: how to display errors in browser

Tags: php, apache, heroku, mailgun

I am hosting a php web app with Heroku, and I have a email service (mailgun) to send emails. My php file handling the email works partially: if I'm in the else condition which contains the sending, my browser is stucked with a blank php page. Otherwise, it works perfectly. I suspect there must be a bug somewhere in the library require or the actual sending, but how I can I display php errors? Usually, on my WAMP server, I would get these big orange alerts in my browser: how can I do that with Heroku?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

between the

For a more permanent solution please consider editing your server's php.ini configuration file or take a look at the method explained here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#view-logs